# The signature of flatMap in Optional of Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

In the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), it appears to be

```
<U> Optional<U> flatMap(Function<? super T,Optional<U>> mapper)
```

For `mapper` as a `Function`, it makes the parameter contra-variant but does not make the return type covariant. I wonder if the `mapper` can (should) be

```
Function<? super T,Optional<? extends U>>
```

or

```
Function<? super T, ? extends Optional<? extends U>>
```

?

Comment: Good question, seems to have been changed in Java 9. `Optional` is a final class so nothing can extend it but `U` might be anything.

Comment: Yes, the function return type should originally have been made covariant. This was fixed in Java 9. See [JDK-8152617](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8152617). Note that the nested wildcard is necessary, even though `Optional` is final. See the review thread (linked from the bug report) for details.

Comment: For future readers a shortcut to a post in the review thread in which Stuart Marks explains to necessity for this change: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-October/044026.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, IMO, since `U` binds to the method itself but not the class `Optional` and also `Optional` is `final`, the current signature should work fine.

If either the two conditions above does not hold, then changes can be applied. Thanks for the [link](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2016-October/044026.html) provided by @MalteHartwig. Let me summarize the answer to this particular question. It becomes clear that if the return type needs to be covariant, the latter signature (the longer one) is necessary in Java 8. It is not only about inheritance. `? extends` is needed in front of `Optional<? extends U>` to declare the user-site variance of `Function` even when `Optional` is `final`. I made a code snippet to demonstrate it:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

class A {}
class B extends A {}

final public class Option<T> {
  private T value;
  public Option(T v) { value = v; }
  <U> Option<? extends U> flatMap1(Function<? super T, Option<? extends U>> mapper) {
    return mapper.apply(value);
  }

  <U> Option<? extends U> flatMap2(Function<? super T, ? extends Option<? extends U>> mapper) {
    return mapper.apply(value);
  }

  void test() {
    Option<A> oa = new Option<>(new A());
    Function<A,Option<A>> faa = (A a) -> new Option<>(new A());
    Function<A,Option<B>> fab = (A a) -> new Option<>(new B());
    //oa.flatMap1(faa);   DOES NOT COMPILE
    oa.flatMap2(fab);
  }
}
```

It seems that since Java only has user-site variance declaration, you may need a series of `? extends` that propagate that declaration all the way to the (2nd) outermost level from the type variable you want to declare variance for.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `class A` and `class B extends A`; you need to remember that an Object `B` is an `A` Object; You inherit from it.

In order for an Object to fulfill the `Optional<? extends U>` constraint, it must have fulfilled the `Optional<U>` constraint. Likewise, in order for an Object to fulfill the `Optional<U>` constraint, it must have fulfilled `Optional<? extends U>`.

They are, in this situation, synonymous terms.

While the question is specific to a certain method, you can test for the answer fairly easily. By writing a similarly function, you can test whether the compiler would allow what you want and whether it would run as expected.

```
public static <U> void List(List<U> A, List<? extends U> B) {
    ...
}
...
MakeList(new ArrayList<Number>(), new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

As expected, everything is fine.